# Creating JSON string from associated array. JavaScript

Tags: javascript, json

I have problems to covert an associated array in JavaScript to JSON object.
The problem is as follow: I have an Array which index are Strings and when I use `JSON.stringify(myArray)` it returns `[]`. If I build my Array as an Object the problem is solved and return `{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}` but the conversion is different. I want a conversion with my Array object like `["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"]`.
It also works fine when my index are numbers but no when are Strings.

How I can do that? I've search the forum for an answer and I found a lot of info but not something like that.

PD: I will let you an example

```
var prueba = new Array();
prueba["key1"] = "value1";
prueba["key2"] = "value2";
```

This dont work when I stringify it.

```
var prueba = new Object();
prueba["key1"] = "value1";
prueba["key2"] = "value2";
```

This works fine but the result is not apropiated to deserialize it in other languages (trust me).

```
var prueba = new Array();
prueba[0] = "value1";
prueba[1] = "value2";
```

This works exactly I want but with numeric index.

Comment: Using objects is the only way... your statement about it being difficult to deserialize it in other languages does not make sense. JSON is JSON. If you have a JSON parser for your language, it will create the appropriate data structure in that language. The result you want, `["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"]`, **is not** JSON. You cannot make `JSON.stringify` produce invalid JSON. If you really want that format, then you have to create your own serializer.

Comment: Perhaps this will aid: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Using_native_JSON#The_replacer_parameter

Comment: The problem is that if I mapping a structure in JAVA to retrieve my JSON array from JavaScript... the language expects an Object, not an Array. I thought it was easy to fix in JavaScript more than in JAVA but... if you are right I have to parse it better in JAVA >_<

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Why not

```
var input = '{"key1":"value1","key2":"value2"}',
    output = input.replace(/^{(.*)}$/, '[$1]');

console.log(output); // >> ["key1":"value1","key2":"value2"]
```

Here `input` is the result of an ordinary `JSON.stringify()`, `output` is the RegExp'ed `input`.

Comment: If I can stringify output... that will be nice! but Felix is right, ["key1":"value1"] is not a correct JSON string. Probably what I looking for is {["key1", "value1"]} but with RegExp will be easy. Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, make the `output = input.replace(/^{(.*)}$/, '{[$1]}');`